# offsetParent.scrollTop doesn't work in most browsers

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Am I doing something wrong? It looks like this only works in IE, though I can't see what I'm expecting that others can't handle.

```
<div id="test" style="height:4em;overflow:scroll;">
one<br />two<br />three<br />four<br />five<br />six<br />seven<br />eight<br />nine<br />ten<br />
<b id="item1">I should come into view!</b>
</div>
<script><!--
document.getElementById("item1").offsetParent.scrollTop=1000;
//--></script>
```

(please don't answer *why don't you use "test"*, because this is a simplified example to demonstrate I have an issue using `offsetParent`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just reading the [documentation on offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent) and looking at what happens in Chrome and Firefox, it's pretty clear that `offsetParent` is being set to the `<body>` element and your div with `id="test"` is not positioned.

If you add `position: relative` to your container div, it will pick up that as the offsetParent and work properly. I don't know if this the fix you are looking for, but it works.

The alternative, of course, is using `.parentElement` instead of `offsetParent`, depending on your use-case.

Comment: `style="position:relative;height:4em;overflow:scroll;"` does the trick, thank you

Answer (score 0):

use `document.getElementById("item1").parentElement.scrollTop = 1000`

offset parent is not meant to find the parent element of a node rather the 
"nearest table cell or root element" which in your case is the `<body>` tag.
See the MDN Doc for [offsetParent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetParent)

Comment: This won't work in the larger application I'm working on, since the item may have the 'scrolling' element on a higher lever then the direct parentElement. I've tried a while loop and continuously getting parentElement until `x.style.overflow="scroll"`, but that didn't work.

Comment: If thats the case then @Vibhu's answer is what you're looking for. Set the element with the scroll to have `position:relative`